# Ag-grid is taking a lot of time to display with multiple Cell Renderer and Value Getter

Tags: ag-grid

I have to render ag-grid table in dialog box.

My grid has multi `cellRenderer, valueGetter and cellRendererParams` in `columnDefs`.
Instead of converting server data to `rowData` and using `field` to render, I have used **valueGetter** to fetch the value from the server data like 
`valueGetter: 'data.screen1.graph.visible'`.

My ag-grid with 13 columns and 150 rows is taking noticeable time to render.
Is it because of `valueGetter` that my table is taking time to render?

**Below is my sample data:**

```js
     private createColumnDefs() {
        this.columnDefs = [{
          headerName: 'Header1',
          cellRenderer: (params) => {
              return params.data.serverObject1.function === 'input' ? 'I' : 'O';
          },
          minWidth: 50,
          width: 70,
        }, {
          headerName: 'Header2',
          field: 'serverObject1.name',
          minWidth: 60,
          width: 80,
        }, {
          headerName: 'Header3',
          field: 'value',
          cellRenderer: 'valueFieldRenderer',
          minWidth: 100,
          width: 250,
        }, {
          headerName: 'Header4',
          cellRenderer: 'checkBoxRenderer',
          valueGetter: 'data.serverObject1.graph.visible',
          cellRendererParams(params) {
            return {
              disabledVal : params.data.localArray.length > 0 || params.data.attribute1 !== null
            };
          },
          minWidth: 70,
          width: 70,
        }, {
          headerName: 'Header5',
          cellRenderer: 'checkBoxRenderer',
          valueGetter: 'data.serverObject1.archive',
          cellRendererParams(params) {
            return {
              disabledVal : params.data.serverObject1.function === 'input'
            };
          },
          minWidth: 70,
          width: 70,
        }, {
          headerName: 'Header6',
          cellRenderer: 'checkBoxRenderer',
          valueGetter: 'data.serverObject1.alarm',
          cellRendererParams(params) {
            return {
              disabledVal : !((params.data.serverObject1.function === 'output') && (params.data.serverObject1.type === 'bool'))
            };
          },
          minWidth: 70,
          width: 70,
        },
          {
            headerName: 'Header7',
            cellRenderer: 'textBoxRenderer',
            valueGetter: 'data.serverObject1.active',
            minWidth: 150,
            width: 150,
          },
          {
            headerName: 'Header8',
            cellRenderer: 'textBoxRenderer',
            valueGetter: 'data.serverObject1.inactive',
            minWidth: 150,
            width: 150,
          },
          {
            headerName: 'Header11',
            cellRenderer: 'textBoxRenderer',
            valueGetter: (params) => params.data.text1,
            minWidth: 150,
            width: 150,
            cellStyle: (params) => {
              return (this.diagram === 'XYZ' &&
                !(params.data.serverObject1.function === 'output' || params.data.serverObject1.type === 'string'
                  || params.data.serverObject1.type === 'int')) ? {display: 'block'} : {display: 'none'};
            }}
        ];
      }
```

**cell renderer:**

```js
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-check-box',
      template:
          `
        <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="params.value" [id]="getID(params)" class="primary small"
               (change)="onChange($event)">
        <label [for]="getID(params)" class="text-hide">hidden</label>
      `,
      styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
    })

    // tslint:disable-next-line:component-class-suffix
    export class CheckBoxRenderer implements AfterViewInit, ICellRendererAngularComp {

      private params: ICellRendererParams;

      constructor(private readonly translateService: TranslateService) { }

      agInit(params: ICellRendererParams): void {
        this.params = params;
      }

      public onChange(event) {
      }

      refresh(params: any): boolean {
        return false;
      }

      public getID(params): string {
        return params.column.colId + params.rowIndex;
      }

      afterGuiAttached(params?: IAfterGuiAttachedParams): void {
      }

      ngAfterViewInit(): void {
      }

      translate(key: string, params?: any): string {
        return this.translateService.instant(key, params);
      }
    }
```

Should I consider converting to `rowData` to decrease loading time?

Comment: can you show your cellRenderers ? and instead of valueGetter you should use the `field` property

Comment: I have added my cell renderer in the question. Also i have tried using field property too but its taking similar time to render. Also almost 10 of my columns have cell renderer.

Comment: @RachidO  ... Any suggestion on the same?

Comment: @RachidO Any suggestion on this?